# c - Pointer's content disappears after usage

Tags: c, pointers

I have this piece of code where `complexp` is a pointer to a `struct` that represents a complex number. The first `printf` command works just fine and `complexp`'s content is printed. However,  the second `printf` does not work properly and prints `0` twice (which is not correct).

There is no code between these two lines.

```
int main()
    {
        ComplexP  complexp =  (ComplexP) malloc(sizeof(ComplexP));
        complexp = fromCharFunc(s);

        printf("complexp: real: %f, imaginary: %f\n", complexp->real, complexp->imaginary);

         printf("1complexp: real: %f, imaginary: %f\n", complexp->real, complexp->imaginary);

    return 0;
    }
 typedef struct Complex {
   double real;
   double imaginary;
 } Complex;

typedef struct Complex* ComplexP;
ComplexP fromCharFunc(char * s)
{
    if(s == NULL)
    {
        return NULL;
    }


char* sreal;
char* simaginary;
double real;
double imaginary;

char str [DEFAULT_SIZE];

strcpy(str, s);
sreal = strtok(str, REALL_PART_DELIMITER);

simaginary = strtok(NULL, IMAGINARY_PART_DELIMITER);

int len1 = strlen(sreal) + strlen(simaginary);
int len2 = strlen(s) - strlen(IMAGINARY_PART_DELIMITER);

int diff = len1 == len2 ? 0 : 1;


if(diff)
{
    return NULL;
}


if(verifyIsNumber(sreal))
{
    real = atof(sreal);
}
else
{
    return NULL;
}

if(verifyIsNumber(simaginary))
{
    imaginary = atof(simaginary);
}
else
{
    return NULL;
}

Complex complex = {real, imaginary};
ComplexP complexp = &complex;

return complexp;

}
/**
 * @brief determines whether a string represents a number
 * @param char *s poiter to a string
 * #retrun 0 if not a number, 1 if is a number
 */
int verifyIsNumber(char *s)
{
char c;
int i = 0;
while( *(s+i) != '\0')
{
    c = *(s+i);
    if ((c >= MIN_DIGIT && c <= MAX_DIGIT) || c == POINT || c == MINUS)
        i++;
    else
    {
        return 0;
    }
}

return 1;

}
```

Comment: Could you show the whole function?

Comment: Show the definition of `complexp` and of its type.

Comment: @ouah the code is just from a main function i use to test the struct which is created by a constructor that returns a pointer (Complexp type)

Comment: I think there is no need to use **typedef struct Complex* ComplexP;** .You have already used typedef before. So you can directly use Complex* ComplexP;

Comment: If there is no code between the `printf` lines you must have undefined behaviour somewhere in your code.

Comment: My guess is complexp has been initialized incorrectly, and because of undefined behavior the first printf just happens to find the correct values in the memory.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `complexp->imaginary` instead of `complexp-imaginary`?

Comment: i've eddited and posted complex's constructor too. how does it makes sense that complexp just happen to find the values by mistake and olny once?

Answer (score 1):

## Response to full code being posted

I was able to reproduce your problem. The problem comes from these lines:

```
ComplexP fromCharFunc(char * s)
{
    /* ... */
    Complex complex = {real, imaginary};
    ComplexP complexp = &complex;

    return complexp;
}
```

Here, `complex` is a stack variable, meaning it will go out of scope once the function returns. The fact that it prints the right answer the first time is a half-coincidence probably based on the fact that the data hasn't yet been overwritten. This is undefined behavior. Use `calloc()` or `malloc()` to allocate your memory if you need your references to survive, and don't forget to `free()` them later. You can see `calloc()` at work in my example, although for the short example I omitted the `free()` call.

## Working example

I tried your code (after turning it into a complete working example, which would have been helpful!), and it works:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct Complex {
    double real;
    double imaginary;
} Complex;

typedef struct Complex* ComplexP;

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    ComplexP complexp = calloc(sizeof(Complex), 1);

    complexp->real = 42;
    complexp->imaginary = 100.5;

    printf("complexp: real: %f, imaginary: %f\n", complexp->real,
                                                  complexp->imaginary);

    printf("complexp: real: %f, imaginary: %f\n", complexp->real,
                                                  complexp->imaginary);

    return 0;
}
```

Thus, there must be something in *code you haven't shown.* I suggest starting with a smaller example, like mine, and adding functionality back in until you find the problem.

## C99 `complex` type

Also, in case you are not aware, [C99 already includes a standard definition for complex numbers](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Complex-Numbers.html). You may wish to have a look at `<complex.h>` to see if it meets your needs.

Comment: at first i didnt allocate any memory at all. so i tried doing it like you did but it still doesnt work.

Comment: I noticed I had a typo in my `calloc()` call. Be sure to take `sizeof(Complex)` (structure size) rather than `sizeof(ComplexP)` (pointer size) as I had in a prior edit. This may have caused some undefined behavior.

Answer (score 1):

You are returning a pointer to a local variable. That variable is deleted at the end of the scope. You should consider returning a `Complex` variable instead of `ComplexP`.

```
ComplexP fromCharFunc(char * s)
{

    // ...

    // This variable is deleted after the function ends
    Complex complex = {real, imaginary};

    // After deletion, this pointer points to invalid memory
    ComplexP complexp = &complex;

    return complexp;
}
```

Your first `printf` call works, because values in `complex` still happen to be in the memory location to which your pointer points. This is undefined behavior. With a different compiler or a different system, it could be so that both `printf` commands fail, or both succeed.

If you want to return `ComplexP`, you should reserve memory using `malloc`.

```
ComplexP fromCharFunc(char * s)
{

    // ...

    // Create a temporary variable
    Complex complex = {real, imaginary};

    // Reserve memory for your return variable
    ComplexP complexp = malloc(sizeof(Complex));

    // Copy your temporary variable to the reserved memory location
    *complexp = complex;

    return complexp;
}
```

Comment: this is a homework assignment. i must return a pointer (and of course, cannot use complex.h)

Comment: In that case, you should initialize pointer using malloc(). I will edit this to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use gdb to debug your program. before you reach to second printf statement your pointer must be freed. This problem can only be solved easily by using gdb.

To trace the problem you must enable debug symbols in your program while compilation. You can do this by providing -g flag.